# Does the placement of files for OpenGL (freeglut) affect development on different machines?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, freeglut

I'm going to develop an OpenGL project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, developing with C++.
I'm intending to use freeglut for the project as it would probably give me more freedom to compute things such as reading a 3D model, displaying the mesh, and performing computations on the 3D model later. Do correct me if I'm wrong here...

I'm assuming that copying the required files for freeglut into my project directory would enable me to work on it using different machines with just linking it once in the Visual Studio project?
I'm still setting up the project at this point and I do have a lot of doubts with regards to getting started on OpenGL even after reading from various sources online.
I have read in some places that it is not advisable to include the freeglut or glut files into the project directory, but instead, create a new directory elsewhere and link to it. I'm at a loss as to what is the better approach or if there is any difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference as such in terms of functionality, But its always recomended to put your libraries someplace else so that you can use them later in some other project without having to copy them again.
Its true for any third party dependancied and not only freeglut.

Secondly AFAIK freeglut is only a windowing API and it does provide some convenient functions to draw 3d primitives etc but it wont help in this

> reading a 3D model, displaying the mesh, and performing computations on the 3D model later.

And yes you will be able to run your application on other machines provided same architecture and platform.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am aware that I would have to code the loader if I am not using other libraries or API. Thank you very much for the reply.